# Ruby if else statement one line not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following properly working line in a view that adds a class depending on the `current_page` of the user:

```
<li class="hvr-bottom <%= 'active' if current_page?(root_path) %>"> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li>
```

Now I would also like to add a different class for the else situation, and I would prefer to do so while keeping it a single line (or is this not possible?) I was thinking of:

```
<li class="hvr-bottom <%= if(current_page?(root_path)) ? 'active' : 'inactive' %>"> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li>
```

This produces the error:

```
syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting keyword_then or ';' or '\n' ...ath)) ? 'active' : 'inactive' );@output_buffer.safe_append='... ... ^
```

*Any idea how I could make this work?* Or is perhaps a single line not possible here?

---

I also tried the line below (which leaves out certain parenthesis) but it has the same result:

```
<li class="hvr-bottom <%= if current_page?(root_path) ? 'active' : 'inactive' %>"> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to use "if" in the ternary. Change your statement to look like this:

```
<%= current_page?(root_path) ? 'active' : 'inactive' %>
```

Comment: For the record, "one line `if`" is `if condition then expression1 else expression2 end` or alternatively `if condition; expression1 else expression2 end`. (In Ruby, you can almost always replace newline with semicolon.)